# python crypto encryption/decryption - can't deal with unicode replacement chars

Tags: python, cryptography

I have a problem with AES encryption/decryption in Python - after decryption I'm receiving unicode replacement characters and I don't know how to do it correctly. From other answers I've found out what my mistake was (I'm working with encrypted text, which are bytes, not string) and I wanted to use `base64`, but I'm getting an error. Here's my try:

```
with open ('pub.key', 'rt') as pub_key:
     public_key = RSA.importKey(pub_key.read())
     base64.b64encode(public_key.encrypt(file_content, key_size))
```

And the error:

```
TypeError: b2a_base64() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not tuple
```

It's probably easy to fix, but I can't find a way to.

**EDIT:**

I've been trying to do as suggested by @Jean-François Fabre, but then I'm still having problems with decoding, I mean I get unicode replacement chars in return.
Here's how I've decoded:

```
with open ('priv.key', 'rt') as priv_key:
     private_key = RSA.importKey(priv_key.read())
     return private_key.decrypt(base64.b64decode(content))
```

And the result is:

```
g��q@~w%8����[��P��"�����?�)���&�q���1�g�}�w��d[�`�0j^y���4p
```

for the input `file_content` having fake structure catalog (`key_size` is **16**):

```
file_content = "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/pawel/custom_folder/documentA.md
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/pawel/custom_folder/catalogA/documentA.md
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/pawel/custom_folder/catalogA/documentB.md
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/pawel/custom_folder/catalogB/documentA.md
Zawartosc katalogu A!
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/pawel/custom_folder/catalogB/other.json
{
 "bank": "ING Online",
 "user": "franek0057",
 "pswd": "fauDA41"
}
----------------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: a [mcve] would be nice. We cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Can you help now? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 0):

from the [documentation](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html):

> encrypt(self, plaintext, K)
>
> Encrypt a piece of data with RSA.
>
> Parameters:

...

> Returns:
>       **A tuple with two items**. The first item is the ciphertext of the same type as the plaintext (string or long). **The second item is always None.**
>   Overrides: pubkey.pubkey.encrypt

So you just have to drop the second item of the tuple to get the encrypted message:

```
base64.b64encode(public_key.encrypt(file_content, key_size)[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still havinf problems with decoding. Please, see my edit.